# In the morning, Rice was eaten by me. Is there any dangling?

Tags: grammaticality, dangling-modifier

**1. I ate rice in the morning.**
**2. In the morning, I ate rice.**
**3. Rice was eaten by me in the morning.**
**4. In the morning, Rice was eaten by me.**

Are they all correct sentencess?
In the last sentence, Is there any dangling ( Either active or passive doesn't matter to me. )?

Comment: Do not capitalize nouns (e.g. "Rice") that do not start a sentence. Only the first two sentences would be commonly used.

Comment: I would like to ask you **why** you chose to ask "rice was eaten by me" which sounds unnatural, just out of my curiosity.

Comment: Some kind of passive-voice school exercise?

Comment: @KentaroTomono, my emphasis is on dangling, not on whether it be active or passive.

Comment: @MohammadAbulHasem Then it is dangling. As vectory puts it, why would you like to make a simple statement to be unusual by making it passive?

Comment: @MohammadAbulHasem No. It lacks **by who**.

Comment: @Kentaro Tomono, If I say, 1. *All over the world, English is spoken.*2. *In today's morning, rice was eaten.* 3. *Rice was eaten in today's morning.* Are they all correct saying? Here,*all over the world* and *in today's morning* are prepositional phrases acting as modifiers. I know modifiers should be placed near the fact to be modified as possible. Otherwise thay would be danglings. Thank you.

Comment: @MohammadAbulHasem Only 1 could be correct. ( Excluding if English is really spoken all over the world. ) Because 1 is describing the general issue. Therefore, you don't have to say **by who**. But 2 is specifying as "In today's morning", you have to specify **who ate the rice**. Same goes with 3. Since I am not a native speaker, please ask Michael Hravery or others to get more deep insight. Thank you ^^.

Comment: @MohammadAbulHasem Not everybody around the world in general eats rice **today's morning**, doesn't it? That's the difference from 1. FYI.

Comment: The difference is more complicated. The standard word order for 1 would be "English is spoken all over the world", or "English is not spoken everywhere, by everyone". @Mohammad your question isn't clear. The only thing I can see dangling is your "dangling" in every other sentenc, which as an attribute, is in the right place, and the dangling allows relative clauses like "Is there any dangling, that I thought was proscribed at least for prepositions", or whatever else you have in mind.

Comment: "In the last sentence, Is there any dangling?" - this seems like a great example of a self-referencing sentence: it is the last sentence of the question, and the word "dangling" is dangling.

Answer (score 1):

> In the morning, I ate rice.

This begs two questions:

> 1. Was it I who ate rice in the morning?

In the morning, I ate rice and my sister ate buckwheat.

OR

> 2. Was it rice that I ate in the morning?

In the morning, I ate rice and in the evening, buckwheat.

Since it's unclear without context what the author had in mind writing this, it sounds odd because of the dangling modifier "in the morning".

At the same time

> I ate rice in the morning

definitely means—that it was I who ate rice, *not some other cereal*, and it was in the morning and *not in the daytime or in the evening.* The same goes for the passive construction "(The) Rice was eaten by me in the morning", strange as it sounds.

Comment: Great. Sorry to vectory, Rompey's answer is very easy to understand.I got so confused by your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Where has the rice gone? It was eaten by me.

This would be unusual, but grammatically correct. It would be very bad style, because it's longer than a simple "I ate rice". You could find "Rice is disliked by so many people", where *people* is indefinite and thus the objective in this context. Definite noun phrases have a tendency to precede the indefinite ones. If we have "A cat caught the mouse", that sounds slightly odd, because the cat is immediately defined as *the* cat that caught the mouse (then it depends, whether you can point at the cat, or whether you rather front the mouse in a passive sentence). The point is, the definite noun phrase reopens a known context, and **that should not be left dangling** *except for suspense or Q&A style*.

That's my take, it's not official grammar, but it's pragmatics.

**Edit**:

Compare

> The man hit the boy
>
> Who did hit the boy? The man.
>
> Whom hit the man? The boy.
>
> Who was hit by the man? The boy.

But not "Who hit the man?", because nobody did hit the man; although the difference between who and whom is fuzzy in common speach. For this reason, a passive construction is preferably:

> What happened to mike? Yesterday he was struck by lightning.

Comment: If I say "In today's morning, a glass was broken by Rony". Is it correct saying? My emphasis is on whether it is dangling or not

Comment: @MohammadAbulHasem BTW, you should say "this morning". At the same time, you can say "yesterday/tomorrow morning", without "'s".

Comment: Your examples: "Who did hit the boy? The man". "Whom hit the man? The boy." So, you have no doubt that it should be "Whom did the man hit?"" Who hit the boy?", do you?

Comment: @Rompey I am actually becoming a little doubtful, because I don't understand the reason for your question, but I am pretty sure about those examples. Why are youasking?

Comment: Then you should revise [Subject and Object Questions](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/subject-questions.html) so that you can get my drift.

Comment: Who hit the man? The other man who saw him hit the boy. Who hit the boy? The man whom the other man hit when he saw the first man hitting the boy. Whom did the second man hit? The man that hit the boy.

Comment: I got more perplexed than before by your answer.

Comment: @rompey oh, I see, but we can say "Who does know the answer?" or informally "who knows the the answer",  so the distinction you are pointing out is not helpful, at least if the verb is irregular and not inflected at all, like *to hit*, so instead asking *whom*, maybe in the object position "the man hit whom?" is disambiguous. Is that sufficient? I chose a confusing example. I just wanted to explore the idea. There is no active construction for "what happened to mike", that's the point? And so mike is left *hangig* of the end of the sentence, passively like that.

Comment: Someone hit the boy. Everyone asked if it was him/her that did it, answers, no, I didn't. This begs the question of who did hit the boy (the person is unknown unlike in your example). I wash my hands, so no more comments from me, especially on.what happened to Mike. Have a nice day.

Comment: Compare a case of a missing purse. One might ask the suspect, "who(m) did you give it (to)", with a true dangling preposition, or alternatively "who has it?", "who received it", "who bought it". If "to" is considered dangling, and perhaps wrong, then maybe that extends to the pronoun object, that is the semantic subject of the question. Thus it would better be "To whom was it given?", perhaps, but dangling is in many ways not really an issue. Now I wonder, what's the correct question to "Mary was given a purse" - Neither "Who was given it" nor "who was it given" are common!?